# Where is the dc component?

Tags: filter, active-filter, passive-filter

So a ac filter doesnt allow the dc component to pass through it, so the dc component would take a altetnative path where as the ac component would easily pass through it. My question is, where is dc component in the input wave?

Comment: It depends on what kind of signal. Every kind of signal can be represented by a sum of sine, cosine and a DC component.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if the filter blocks DC, then it doesn't "go" anywhere. It simply appears across whatever component inside the filter that's doing the blocking, such as a capacitor.

Comment: @LongPham, to be more precise, every _periodic_ signal can be decomposed into a sum of sinusoids and a DC component. Finite, non-periodic signals can be _approximately_ understood by pretending that they were [snipped from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) an infinitely long periodic signal.

Comment: @besmirched: To be even more precise, nonperiodic signals can be represented with sines and cosines if you allow an infinite number of them. The Fourier Transform does not require periodicity.

Comment: @DaveTweed I dont know anything about fourier series etc... It will probably start next semester... So you are saying the input sine wave can be expressed as a sum of trig terms, and as we approach infinity the graph of the terms become flatter and flatter? ie a dc component?

Answer (score 2):

DC component is the average amplitude over a cycle time period of the signal. So, basically in simple terms you can call the DC component as the bias given to an oscillating signal. For a sinusoidal signal with no bias it would be 0.